# How to get audio file metadata container's data for flac and ogg

Tags: linux, file, id3, flac, vorbis

Is there a command to tell me what type of metadata container is using a file?

Something like: `command myfile.flac` saying: `vorbis comment` or `id3v2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warning: One audio file can have multiple metadata containers. So finding vorbis comment doesn't mean there is no id3 tags. Reminder: flac and ogg should be used with vorbis comment.

## Vorbis comment

### Flac

```
metaflac --list myfile.flac
```

It will print a lot of info for each block. Here is the answer:

```
METADATA block #2
  type: 4 (VORBIS_COMMENT)
```

To install metaflac: `sudo apt install flac`.

### Ogg

```
vorbiscomment file.ogg
```

It will output something like:

```
encoder=Lavc57.107.100 libvorbis
TRACKNUMBER=1
title=My file title
...
```

To install: `sudo apt install vorbis-tools`

## ID3

Well, the best thing I found is a python library: `mutagen`. For example, in your python file you can write:

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3NoHeaderError, ID3

try:
    tags = ID3("path/to/myfile.ogg")
    print("ID3 tags found: ", tags)
except ID3NoHeaderError:
    print("No ID3 tags")
```

Output for file with ID3 tags: `ID3 tags found:  {'TIT2': TIT2(encoding=<Encoding.UTF8: 3>, text=['my new title'])}`. It works also for flac files.

Comment: That's neither "a" (but instead multiple), nor a "command" (but instead 3rd party software). How about at least linking to each? Also keep in mind that multiple metadata systems can be used in one file, not only one.

Comment: If it's http://nekohako.xware.cx/id3tool/ then it will only recognize ID3v1 and only in MP3 files, not in WAV, IFF, ASF.

Comment: thank's for your comments, I've modified the answer.